# How can I use RelativeLayout to align buttons to the right of an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-relativelayout

I'm struggling with a simple relative layout.  It is supposed to have an image on the left and a column of other views on the right.  The vertical alignment is correct but the horizontal alignment is very puzzling with the buttons on the left of the image even though I have asked for them to be on the right.
Can anyone explain:

- why this happens,
- how to achieve the arrangement I want.

Here is the layout xml and a screenshot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget51"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/ivLove"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvDate"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:hint="Image name"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivImage"
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvPage"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="Page URL"
      android:layout_below="@+id/tvDate"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivImage"
      />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnNext"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Next"
      android:layout_below="@+id/tvPage"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivImage"
      />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Previous"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btnNext"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivImage"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

In case you are wondering about the image see [Android : Simple HTML parsing & image downloader using AsyncTask](http://adanware.blogspot.no/2012/07/android-simple-html-parser-image.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting those controls (`TextView`, `Button`) on the right side of the `ImageView` with id **ivImage**.

However, your layout does not contain any ImageView with that id (but has one with **ivLove**). 
The controls appear on the left because that's the default docking for views inside a `RelativeLayout`.

Try updating your references (replace each "**ivImage**" with "**ivLove**".

**Note -- if you use Eclipse**, that the reason you didn't get compile errors for this is that you probably have an `ImageView` with `android:id="ivImage"` somewhere in your project. Enabling (and maybe updating) lint will help you filter these kinds of issues.

Comment: For goodness sake, that's so embarrassing!  I was at least a 100% sure I had checked for exactly that sort of problem. Thanks for pointing it out.  Now it works. I'm using Emacs and cedet with the compiler from Android Studio and I tried using lint on (lint: version 23.0.5) the xml file but it didn't find anything (or perhaps I don't understand how to drive lint).

Comment: Don't be embarrassed, this is how we all learn. [Lint is a pretty tool, but it can make you lazy and less sensitive to typos.]

Comment: I know it's how we learn but it's embarrassing because I've been coding for over 40 years, 30 of those as part or all of my job. My only defence is that I am very new to Android, but still I really should have seen that. By the way, thanks for an incredibly quick response.